# jbpm don't know the jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm

I am the first time for JBPM. When I create object, the project do not know the jar file. Please help me.

The following is my step by step installation.

```
1.I installed the JBPM plugin in Eclipse Kepler.
2.I extract the jbpm-6.0.1.Final-installer-full.jar in D:
3.I create new projct in Eclipse.
4.After that they do not known jar file.
```

Please see my image.

[image]

Thank in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a jBPM runtime (point it to a folder containing the right version of the jBPM libraries you want to use) first.

I would recommend using the installer script to generate a fully preconfigured eclipse environment.

If you want to manually do this:
 - unzip the -bin zip from jbpm-installer/lib to a folder
 - in eclipse preferences, under jBPM, create a new jBPM runtime and point to the folder you just created
 - restart eclipse for the changes to take effect